# How can I develop and test an Android SMS app without having to be the default SMS handler

Tags: android, sms

We are developing an alert app that will automatically send MMS messages in certain emergency situations.  We think it will qualify as an alert app exception and not be required to be the default SMS handler when we put in in the Play Store.  But we aren't ready for that yet.  In the mean time, developing and testing this app is very difficult because we have to make it the default SMS handler to run it.  Our app is in no way capable of functioning as the default SMS handler.  So, is there any way to get around this requirement while we are developing the app?

Comment: I think you're confused.  You don't need to be the default SMS app to send an SMS.  You can just use SMSManager.sendTextMessage.  You need to be the default SMS app to write or alter the SMS database of sent and received messages.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Actually, we are using SMSManager.sendMultimediaMessage.  This requires a URI parameter that points to a PDU.  To construct the PDU we need the line number from the sim card... telephonyManager.getLine1Number() .  Previously we used android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.  This now requires default handler status.  However in api 26 they added android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS which doesn'

Comment: YOIu do know that getLineNumber1() is not assured to work, right?  That depending on how the SIM is set up the device may not know its own number.  It also may not be the correct number to use in the case of a dual SIM device.  Admittedly both of these are corner cases and its mostly correct

Comment: No, I didn't know that.  I'll have to account for this.  Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [our](https://clicksend.com) SMS gateway, you can use our "test numbers".

Our list of test numbers is:

```
+61411111111
+61422222222
+61433333333
+61444444444
+14055555555
+14055555666
+447777777777
+447778888888
+8615555555555
```

You would need to open a free account at clicksend.com and there is no charge for using test numbers.  Of course, your test messages just go into /dev/null - maybe that's not what you need.

Don't know if that solves your specific problem, but maybe it's a piece of the puzzle. :shrug:

I can have our mobile dev team chime in if you want more help.

Michael
(Software Development Manager, ClickSend - an SMS Gateway Provider)